# Plot vertical arrow when for inf values in GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a simple dataset with X-Y data, that I plot using GNUPlot. Some of the values are inf, and are not plotted. Would it be possible to add a vertical arrow at the top of the graph for these values?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: See Tom Solid's answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
plot 'aro.dat'
plot 'aro.dat' u ($2=="inf"?$1:1/0):(GPVAL_Y_MIN):(0):(GPVAL_Y_MAX-GPVAL_Y_MIN) with vectors notitle, 'aro.dat'
```

? The first `plot` updates the variables `Y_MIN` and `Y_MAX`, then the second `plot` plots an arrow where the second column is "inf".

[image]